# How to get the list of docker images from Azure private registry

Tags: azure, docker

I have a linux system where I have installed dockers. I also have a registry on azure for which I have the user name and password. To get a list of docker images from a private registry we can simply use `curl` command like below:

```
curl localhost:5000/v2/_catalog
```

This command I tested when I installed private registry on my machine and it was giving me the list of images which I have in the registry. Now I have azure registry. I can login to it successfully but don't know what command I can run to get the list of docker images. Is this possible.? For example, if I run:

```
curl myregistry.azurecr.io/v2/_catalog
```

It shows:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>  
</html>
```

How do I get the list of images stored in azure registry from my linux machine

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As yamenk said, you could use [Azure CLI 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) to get your registry on azure.

Azure Cli 2.0 works on linux and docker, so I think it could work your linux machine.

Also, you could use Azure Rest APi to get registry on azure.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<rg>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/<registry name>?api-version=2017-10-01
```

For get token, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-curl-rest#get-an-authentication-token).

Using API like below:

```
curl -X "GET" "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/********/resourceGroups/shuiapp/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/shuitest?api-version=2017-10-01" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use the container registry cli for azure:

```
az acr repository list --name <acrName> --output table
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-azure-cli

Comment: So this is not possible from linux machine.? I know I can do it from azure cli but was just wondering if this is possible from linux machine where docker is installed.

Comment: The ACR does not provide a web api(not documented). You can't assume that they have the same docker registry provided by Docker. They might have their own implementation.

Comment: that command lists repositories not images

Answer (score 18):

It is important to understand how docker lists the images in the registry.
Docker CLI provides command to **pull/push/delete** images from a private Azure Registry like **myprivate.azurecr.io** after the user authenticates itself using docker login command but the docker CLI does not provide any command to list the images in the private registry.

It is important to understand that the ***docker image ls*** only lists the images present on the local machine and not in a registry.
There are multiple answers that describe the Docker HTTP API V2 (Refer [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/)) to list the images present in the registry. The HTTP v2 API **v2/_catalog** and other only work with local registry created on-premise but when user wants to list the images present in the Private Azure Registry one needs to use **Azure CLI**

**What is Local Registry ?**

The Registry is a stateless, highly scalable server side application that stores and lets you distribute Docker images. The Registry is open-source, under the permissive Apache license. Local Registry can be created to store and distribute images in house or on-premise.
Refer here : https://docs.docker.com/registry/ . One can create a private registry,push and pull image from there using Dokcker HTTP API V2.

Azure CR is a special type and inorder to list the images there is no other option to Azure CLI.

**Use Case**
- List the top three images present in the registry
The command for the same can be

```
az acr repository show-tags -n <RegistryName> --repository <RepositoryName> --orderby time_desc --output table | select -First 5
```

Answer (score 4):

Not used to Azure I accidentally got stuck on the idea that I needed the Azure credentials to access the API, these answers strengthening that perception, but given you have the u/p you should be able to access it with curl in a simple:

```
curl -L --user <username>:<password> myregistry.azurecr.io/v2/_catalog 

{"repositories":["name1", "name2", "nameN"]}
```

Comment: I think this is a good answer!  Especially if using command line!